# match pattern and print corresponding columns from a file using awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a input file with repetitive headers (below):

```
A1BG A1BG A1CF A1CF A2ML1
aa bb cc dd ee
1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to print all columns with same header in one file. e.g for above file there should be three output files; 1 for A1BG with 2 columns; 2nd for A1CF with 2 columns; 3rd for A2ML1 with 1 column. I there any way to do it using one-liners by awk or grep?

I tried following one-liner:

```
awk -v f="A1BG" '!o{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x==f){o=1;next}}o{print $x}' trial.txt
```

but this searches the pattern in only one column (1 in this case). I want to look through all the header names and print all the corresponding columns which have A1BG in their header.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a one-liner? Are you running out of newlines? You'll get much more enthusiastic help in this forum if you don't ask for a one-liner as that just makes everyone cringe and then later you can take whatever well-formatted, readable script you get and cram it onto one line if you feel that is beneficial to you for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:

code for step1.awk:

NR == 1 { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
            for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { f2c[$i] = (f2c[$i]=="")? "$" i : (f2c[$i] " \"\t\" $" i) } }
  NR== 2 { for( fn in f2c) printf("%s:%s\n", fn,f2c[fn]) 
           exit
        }

Then run one liner which uses above awk script:

awk -f step1.awk file.txt | awk -F : 'BEGIN {print "{"}; {print "  print " $2, "> \""  $1".txt" "\""  }; END { print "}" }'| awk -f - file.txt

This outputs tab delimited .txt files having all the columns with same header in one file. (separate files for each type of header)

Thanks Lars Fischer and others.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with a 1-liner but here is a 10-liner for GNU awk:

**script.awk**

```
  NR == 1 { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
            for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { f2c[$i] = (i==1)? i : f2c[$i] " " i } }
        { for( n in f2c ) { 
              split( f2c[n], fls, " ")
              tmp = ""
              for( f in fls ) tmp = (f ==1) ? $fls[f] : tmp "\t" $fls[f]
              print tmp > n
          }
        }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk your_file`

In the first action: it determines filenames from the columns in the first record (`NR == 1`).

In the second action: for each record: for each output file: its columns (as defined in the first record) are collected into `tmp` and written to the output file.

The use of PROCINFO requires GNU awk, see Ed Mortons comments for alternatives.

Example run and ouput:

```
> awk -f mpapccfaf.awk mpapccfaf.csv 
> cat A1BG 
A1BG    A1BG
aa      bb
1       2
```

Comment: This doesn't give me desired output. I need all the columns printed with same header in one file (e.g for A1BG there should be one file with two complete columns). The one liner I mentioned it does the work but it just checks in specified column (x=1). i want to modify it so that it looks in complete header row and prints all the columns which have A1BG in their header. thanks

Comment: @aan Please add example output for the files derived from the example input (the *desired output*). If you want the headers in the files: remove the `next` .

Comment: form above input, the desired output for A1BG is:tab delimited file ( 2 cols n 3 rows)                                                                                                     A1BG A1BG
ab bg
1 2         similarly for other labels.

Comment: @aan I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: it does the job partially. It prints one entry per pattern; eg. for A1BG it prints only first column in the file, whereas I need to print all the columns which have A1BG in its header (2 cols in this case).

Comment: @aan I added example run and output: for me it just works. It must be related to the field splitting. What is the field separator that your awk uses, what is the field separator used in the files? (I just copy/pasted your example, giving me space as delimiter in mpapccfaf.csv, but I have just tested the script: it also works for me with tabs as separator).  Btw. I am using gnu awk 4.1.3 with Linux.

Comment: @aan You could add `print NF` in the first action, to see how many fields are recognised.

Comment: @aan If it is really the separator, you could try `awk -v 'FS=\t' ... ` or whatever is used in your input file.

Comment: `for( f in fls )` visits the indices of `fls` in "random" (actually hash) order so you can't assume that the first time through the loop `f` will be `1` so you can't do `(f ==1) ? $fls[f] : tmp "\t" $fls[f]` to prepend with a tab or not. In general you can't test for `tmp` being null either as there COULD be empty fields - you need an iteration counter (see what I did with `c` in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39067134/1745001) or more simply to use `for (f=1; f in fls; f++)` as the loop or save the return from split() as the loop end value.

Comment: Also - note that `f2c[$i] = f2c[$i] i " "; .... split( f2c[n], fls, " ")` means that as written`fls`, and so your output, will have a spurious null field at the end of each line

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your comments. I changed For my version of gnu awk and the given data, there is no difference with or without the procinfo statement.

Comment: @LarsFischer You're welcome. The fact there's no difference is a coincidence caused by the hashing order just happening to be the same as the index order for this particular input set on this particular system. With more input values and/or on a different system the order WILL be different. You **NEED** the procinfo statement to ensure a specific order for the `in` operator - see [Controlling-Array-Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal).

Comment: @LarsFischer. Tried it again, on another system with GNU Awk 3.1.7. It worked well with test data that I mentioned. But when i run it on actual data which has more than 20,000 columns (repetitive headers) it doesn't give right output (just prints 3 columns for each type of header, whereas there are more than three columns with that header). FYI: when I run the script it displays order1 order2 order3....so on (in new line).

Comment: @aan Sorry I have no idea where the problem is. Does one of the other answers work? Can you create a subset of the input, (say 100 columns) to rule out a problem with the huge count of columns?

Comment: @LarsFischer seems like there is sth in the code that restricts it to print (or looks upto) only 3 entries per pattern. it works fine as long as entries are 3 or less than 3. For a pattern which is repeated more than 3 times it just prints first 3 columns and skips rest to look for second repetitive pattern. I am unable to figure out..could you suggest some changes in your script.

Answer (score 1):

awk solution should be pretty fast - output files are tab-delimited and named cols.A1BG cols.A1CF etc

```
awk '
# fill cols columns map to header and tab map to track tab state per header
NR==1 {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    cols[i]=$i
    tab[$i]=0
  }
}
{
# reset tab state for every header
  for(h in tab) tab[h]=0
# write tab-delimited column to its cols.header file
  for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    hdr=cols[i]
    of="cols." hdr
    if(tab[hdr]) {
      printf("\t") >of
    } else
      tab[hdr]=1
    printf("%s", $i) >of
  }
# newline for every header file
  for(h in tab) {
    of="cols." h
    printf("\n") >of
  }
}
'
```

This is the output from both of my awk solutions:

```
$ ./scr.sh <in.txt; head cols.*
==> cols.A1BG <==
A1BG    A1BG
aa      bb
1       2

==> cols.A1CF <==
A1CF    A1CF
cc      dd
3       4

==> cols.A2ML1 <==
A2ML1
ee
5
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk solution takes the same approach as Lars but uses gawk 4.0 2D arrays

```
awk '
# fill cols map of header to its list of columns
NR==1 {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    if(!($i in cols))
      j=0
    cols[$i][j++]=i
  }
}
{
# write tab-delimited columns for each header to its cols.header file
  for(h in cols) {
    of="cols."h
    for(i=0; i < length(cols[h]); ++i) {
      if(i > 0) printf("\t") >of
      printf("%s", $cols[h][i]) >of
    }
    printf("\n") >of
  }
}
'
```

Comment: removed next from processing of first line to print headers to output files

Comment: By convention and as populated by all awk functions, etc., awk array indices and field numbers and string indices all start at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here y'go, a one-liner as requested:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i][i]}{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for(n in a){c=0;for(f in a[n])printf"%s%s",(c++?OFS:""),$f>n;print"">n}}' file
```

The above uses GNU awk 4.* for true multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in.

For anyone else reading this who prefers clarity over the brevity the OP needs, here it is as a more natural multi-line script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        names2fldNrs[$i][i]
    }
}
{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (name in names2fldNrs) {
        c = 0
        for (fldNr in names2fldNrs[name]) {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $fldNr > name
        }
        print "" > name
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file

$ cat A1BG
A1BG A1BG
aa bb
1 2

$ cat A1CF
A1CF A1CF
cc dd
3 4

$ cat A2ML1
A2ML1
ee
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote in one of the comments to my other answer that you have 20000 columns, lets consider a two step approach to ease debugging to find out which of the steps breaks.

**step1.awk**

```
  NR == 1 { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
            for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { f2c[$i] = (f2c[$i]=="")? "$" i : (f2c[$i] " $" i) } }
  NR== 2 { for( fn in f2c) printf("%s:%s\n", fn,f2c[fn]) 
           exit
        }
```

Step1 should give us a list of files together with *their* columns:

```
> awk -f step1.awk yourfile
Mpap_1:$1, $2, $3, $5, $13, $19, $25
Mpap_2:$4, $6, $8, $12, $14, $16, $20, $22, $26, $28
Mpap_3:$7, $9, $10, $11, $15, $17, $18, $21, $23, $24, $27, $29, $30
```

In my test data Mpap_1 is the header in column 1,2,3,5,13,19,25. Lets hope that this first step works with your large set of columns. (To be frank: I dont know if awk can deal with $20000.)

Step 2: lets create one of those famous one liners:

```
> awk -f step1.awk yourfile | awk -F : 'BEGIN {print "{"}; {print "  print " $2, "> \""  $1 "\""  }; END { print "}" }' | awk -v "OFS=\t" -f - yourfile
```

The first part is our step 1, the second part builds on-the-fly a second awk script, with lines like this: `print $1, $2, $3, $5, $13, $19, $25 > "Mpap_1"`. This second awk script is piped to the third part, which read the script from stdin (`-f -`) and applies the script to your input file.

In case something does not work: watch the output of each part of step2, you can execute the parts from the left up to (but not including) each of the `|` symbols and see what is going on, e.g.:

- `awk -f step1.awk yourfile`
- `awk -f step1.awk yourfile | awk -F : 'BEGIN {print "{"}; {print "  print " $2, "> \""  $1 "\""  }; END { print "}" }'`

Comment: Yes it is working. I have run it on full dataset, hopefully will work on such big file. But the output has no delimiter. i need a tab separated .txt files as output. is it possible to get the same?

Comment: @aan use `awk -v "OFS=\t" -f - large.csv` in the last part. (I will update my answer.)

Comment: I already tried this (tried again now), but its not giving a tab separated output. My input is also a tab separated .txt file. BTW I am running it with GNU Awk 3.1.7.

Comment: @aan if `-v "OFS=\t"`  does not work (why?), you can change the first *for loop* in step1.awk into `for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { f2c[$i] = (f2c[$i]=="")? "$" i : (f2c[$i] " \"\\t\" $" i) } ` and omit the `-v "OFS=\t"` in the last part of the second step.