# Merge two file based on a common key in both files using awk

Tags: awk, merge

I am a beginner so apologies if this has been covered before, but I can't seem to find exactly what I need. I am attempting to merge two files based on a common column in both files.

file1

```
2:16641345_T_C -6.7483 49.4866 0.8915
3:14503229_A_C 1.5627 1.2460 0.2098
8:13381223_AT_A -0.0255 0.7766 0.9738
13:58575029_G_A 8.4617 64.4474 0.8955
2:203233108_A_C -7.5032 63.4653 0.9059
22:35773673_G_C -0.6282 1.2473 0.6145
4:76220798_A_T -0.0413 0.0459 0.3682
2:106567150_T_C 0.0011 0.0471 0.9819
3:68098578_T_C 0.0169 0.0429 0.6934
```

file2

```
2:16641345_T_C C T 6.53133e-05
3:14503229_A_C C A 0.000297125
8:13381223_AT_A A AT 0.000773358
13:58575029_G_A A G 0.000320199
2:203233108_A_C C A 0.000158051
22:35773673_G_C C G 0.000446161
4:76220798_A_T T A 0.339496
2:106567150_T_C C T 0.298242
3:68098578_T_C C T 0.52789
```

The first column is common across both files. The desired output is:

Output

```
2:16641345_T_C  C T 6.53133e-05 -6.7483 49.4866 0.8915
3:14503229_A_C C A 0.000297125  1.5627 1.2460 0.2098
etc...
```

I have tried the following but it only gives me the second column of file 2 in the output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1) in a{print $0, a[$1]}' file1 file2
2:16641345_T_C C T 6.53133e-05 -6.7483
3:14503229_A_C C A 0.000297125 1.5627
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you can use join command like join file2 file1 without awk.

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the first column with the corresponding line in the other file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {data[$1]=$0; next} {$1=data[$1]}1' f2 f1
```

You can also use `join` like this, telling it to glue based on the 1st field on both files:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 f2 f1
join -j 1 f2 f1        # -j is equivalent to -1 FIELD -2 FIELD
join f2 f1             # The default join field is the first /
                       #   delimited  by whitespace
```

Even though it is always best to `sort` the files prior to calling `join`, so the correct solution would be:

```
join <(sort f2) <(sort f1)
```

All of the above commands return the following with your given input:

```
2:16641345_T_C C T 6.53133e-05 -6.7483 49.4866 0.8915
3:14503229_A_C C A 0.000297125 1.5627 1.2460 0.2098
8:13381223_AT_A A AT 0.000773358 -0.0255 0.7766 0.9738
13:58575029_G_A A G 0.000320199 8.4617 64.4474 0.8955
2:203233108_A_C C A 0.000158051 -7.5032 63.4653 0.9059
22:35773673_G_C C G 0.000446161 -0.6282 1.2473 0.6145
4:76220798_A_T T A 0.339496 -0.0413 0.0459 0.3682
2:106567150_T_C C T 0.298242 0.0011 0.0471 0.9819
3:68098578_T_C C T 0.52789 0.0169 0.0429 0.6934
```

Comment: @VanishaMistry nice to read! Remember you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: you don't need explicit `-j1` for `join` it's the default.  The files need to be sorted though.

Comment: @karakfa oh nice, this is even shorter then. Updated, many thanks

Comment: As @karakfa points out, `join` won't work without sorting the files first, e.g. `join <(sort file2) <(sort file1)` and then the output won't be in the input order. Alternatively in this case since the input is to be joined line by line you could use `paste file2 <(cut -f2- file1)`.

Comment: @EdMorton mmm not really. With this exact files there is no need to have them sorted, since indexes appear in the same order. `diff -y <(awk 'FNR==NR {data[$1]=$0; next} {$1=data[$1]}1' f2 f1) <(join f2 f1)` reveals the same output. This being said, I am not a big fan of `join` and I prefer `awk` to have a good view on what I am doing.

Comment: From `join --help`: `Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields.` so YMMV wrt indices that aren't sorted even if they are in the same order.

Comment: @EdMorton I am becoming a big fan of urbandictionary.com to decipher what all these initials (_YMMV_, _wrt_) mean :D So yes, my `join` also says this but in this specific case it worked well without having them sorted.

Comment: Many people write awk scripts using `for (i in array) print i` and think all is well when they get the output in numeric order of array indices and then sometimes debate it when I tell them that was just coincidence (e.g. see the comments about procinfo under http://stackoverflow.com/a/39065382/1745001). My point is, if you choose not to do what the man page tells you to do then getting the output you expect from one input set does not mean the solution will work for some other input set or some other tool version or on some other platform. Maybe it will though, _idk_ ;-).