# Compare two columns from Different Files, and print an output from the second file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have two csv files:

1- First file contains:

```
14F6101,123456
14F6102,951357
14F6101,123456
14F6103,753159
```

2- Second file contains:

```
14F6101,x1,y1
14F6102,x2,y2
14F6103,x3,y3
14F6104,x4,y4
```

What I need is a linux script that prints the lines of the first file in case the value of the first column in the first file exists in the second file.

So the output will be:

```
14F6101,123456
14F6102,951357
14F6101,123456
14F6103,753159
```

Moreover, I need to add the values (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) that correspond with each value in the second file. So, the output will be:

```
14F6101,123456,x1,y1
14F6102,951357,x2,y2
14F6101,123456,x1,y1
14F6103,753159,x3,y3
```

I tried something like this, but I could not form the whole thing:

```
awk -v condition="$condition" 'condition { print $1 }' "$1" > temp1.txt
awk -v condition="$condition" 'condition { print $2 }' "$2" > temp2.txt
```

Please feel free to disregard my approach and propose a new one.

Comment: Search answers using `NR==FNR`

Comment: OR, read about the *nix `join` command (assuming it is OK to sort your data (and there are work arounds for that too) ) . Good luck.

Comment: please update the question with a sample of what's in the `$condition` variable; also, show the contents of `temp1.txt` and `temp2.txt`; lastly, update the samples to include a couple lines that do not match your condition (ie, lines that will not have a match in the 2nd file)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080047/merge-two-file-based-on-a-common-key-in-both-files-using-awk)?

Comment: Thanks @GillesQuénot - this must be the first time I see you **not** pouncing on an obvious dupe with an answer. ;)